# Only log for specific .exe in folder with multiple .exe for Nlog config

Tags: executable, nlog

Is there a way to target a specific .exe to log through the Nlog config file? Right now I have like 6 .exe that use the same Nlog config and if I turn on debug for the database it logs for all of them. I only want to target a specific .exe that is running.  Is there a way to do this through the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your six different applications have different namespaces, you can set up different rules for each of them.

```
<rules>
    <logger name="SomeNamespace.Component.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" final="true" />
</rules>
```

Comment: Well they do but the internal projects they reference are the same.  Does that matter? Like SomeNamspace.Data is the database project it references?